# INSERT INTO с условием WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо сделать вставку в таблицу строк с отмеченными чекбоксами. Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $id) 
    { 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO torder (`ID_RequestDriver`, `ID_Person`) VALUES (".$idreqdr.",".$iddr.") WHERE ID_RequestDriver = " . (int) $id; 
        mysql_query($sql); 
    }
```

Но уже на этапе подсветки синтаксиса код "ругается" на условие WHERE. Возможно ли вообще делать вставку в таблицу, используя условие WHERE? И если возможно, как это реализовать правильно в моем случае?

Comment: Если записи уже есть - их не надо INSERT'ить, их нужно UPDATE'ить. И, почитайте про INSERT.... ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас какая-то странная логика - объясните словами что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Условие where фильтрует _существующие_ в таблице строки. А insert создает _новые_. Ваше условие сейчас буквально звучит "вставь в таблицу torder запись с id=X в случае, если в таблице уже есть запись с id=X". Т.е. если бы такой синтаксис был, то вы бы не добавили ни одной совершенно новой записи, потому что условие гласит, что запись уже должна быть в таблице перед вставкой

Comment: Записей в таблице еще нет, UPDATE'ить там нечего. Подробнее - я вывожу список из одной "таблицы А". Я отмечаю чекбоксами нужные мне строки списка, и во вторую "таблицу В" заношу ID отмеченной строки и ID текущего пользователя сайта.

Comment: @Nataly как я понял, вы уже в цикле отбираете нужные вам строки. Уберите Where, добавьте нужные вам айдишники(скорее всего эти айдишники нужно вытаскивать из обрабатываемого в данной итерации элемента)

Comment: @PavelNewSky, я в цикле только перебираю строки со всеми чекбоксами, а условие мне нужно, чтобы действие производилось над чекбоксом с нужным мне id.

Comment: Если записей еще нет, то зачем вообще нужен where, что он проверяет ?

Comment: @Nataly логика должна быть такой, даже если вы перебираете в цикле абсолютно все строки с чекбоксами, значит нужно добавить условие, которое будет проверять айдишники, для которых отмечены чекбоксы и добавлять insert'ом конкретно их

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подозреваю, что это вот то, что требуется

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $id) 
{ 
    if ($idreqdr == (int) $id) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO torder (`ID_RequestDriver`, `ID_Person`) VALUES (".$idreqdr.",".$iddr.")"; 
        mysql_query($sql); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Когда я делаю с условием, в таблицу вообще не добавляются записи... Если без условия if, запись добавляется, но не та... Я чувствую, что решение где-то рядом, но не могу понять, где.

Comment: Пытясь отловить ошибку, я сделала вывод "echo var_dump($_POST['check']);" и "echo $idreqdr;". И вот в чем загвозка - я отмечаю чекбоксом запись с id = 50, в var_dump мне заносится запись с id = 50. а в $idreqdr у меня лежит запись с id = 51...

Comment: Может вы откуда-то не оттуда берете значение для переменной $idreqdr? Судя по вашему комментарию, предложенный мной кусок кода правильный, просто ему на вход подаются неверный данные

Comment: Скорее всего, так и есть. Я пытаюсь передать значение переменной php через отправку формы разными способами, но каждый раз выходит что-то не то. Сейчас я поправила код и передаю так: " echo '<input type="hidden" name="idreqdr[]" placeholder="0" value="'.$row["ID_RequestDriver"].'">'; ". Он мне присылает массив с id 50 и 51. А мне нужно как-то получить только 50...

Comment: В общем, я, кажется, разобралась. Так как у меня id заявки и id чекбокса - одинаковы, я сделала так:

 " foreach($_POST['check'] as $id) 
 {  $sql = "INSERT INTO torder (`ID_RequestDriver`, `ID_Person`) VALUES (".$id.",".$iddr.")"; 
         mysql_query($sql); 
     } " Этот вариант работает, как надо.

Answer (score 1):

В синтаксисе запроса INSERT INTO не может быть WHERE. Используйте UPDATE!
INSERT добавляет в таблицу новые строки, а UPDATE изменяет уже существующие.